# Get data from firestore and put into list (flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have retrieve data from Firestore db and put into list but error occur. Furthermore, the dialog on exception block doesn't trigger at all.

```
class mDetail extends State<homeDetail>{
bool uniFlag = false;
var resultUni;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    try {
      UniQuery().getUniBasedLocProg(selectedState,selectedProg).then((QuerySnapshot qsUni) {
        uniFlag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < qsUni.documents.length; i++) {
          resultUni.add(qsUni.documents[i]['name']);
        }
      });
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e.message);
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Ops something gone wrong'),
              content: Text('Your email or password is wrong'),
            );
          });
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('EduGradHomePage'),),
      body: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: back,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.backspace
                ),
              ),

              Text(resultUni[0])
            ],
          )
    )
    );
  }
}
```

this code in other package for uniquery

```
class UniQuery {
  getUniBasedLocProg(String uniLoc, String uniProg){
    return dbReference.collection('University')
        .where('State', isEqualTo: uniLoc)
        .where('Programme', isEqualTo: uniProg)
        .getDocuments();
  }
}
```

IT say error NoSuchMethodError
The method '[]' was calleed on null
seems like the value doesnot add in the list

here my DB in firestore

[list Programme data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lmXK.png)

[list University data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsJVH.png)

[list State data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjS5C.png)

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOBnJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

after i change to bellow code. i manage to get the value
*idState* and *idProg* are the id based on the document of collection in my firestore

```
 class UniQuery {
      getUniBasedLocProg(String uniLoc, String uniProg){
        return dbReference.collection('University')
            .where('State', isEqualTo: dbReference.collection('State')
            .document(idState);)
            .where('Programme', isEqualTo: dbReference.collection('Programme')
            .document(idProg);)
            .getDocuments();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

.getUniBasedLocProg(selectedState,selectedProg) is future callback so it's return data 
   after taking some times.during that build also build your code.so that time it's was 
   null that's why you get an error "The method '[]' was calleed on null".

so before use that variable check that's is null or not.

```
       resultUni[0] ?? "" // if not null then return value otherwise return "" //
```

full code ->

```
   class mDetail extends State<homeDetail>{
   bool uniFlag = false;
   var resultUni;
    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
try {
  UniQuery().getUniBasedLocProg(selectedState,selectedProg).then((QuerySnapshot qsUni) 
    {
    uniFlag = true;
    if(qsUni !=null&&qsUni.documents !=null ){
     for (int i = 0; i < qsUni.documents.length; i++) {

      if(qsUni.documents[i] !=null ){
      resultUni.add(qsUni.documents[i]['name']);
      }
    }
  }
  });
}
catch(e){
  print(e.message);
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Ops something gone wrong'),
          content: Text('Your email or password is wrong'),
        );
      });
   }
 }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('EduGradHomePage'),),
  body: Form(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: back,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.backspace
            ),
          ),

          Text(resultUni[0] ?? ""),
        ],
      )
  )
 );
 }
 }
```

Comment: i got same error though
i have put class for getting data in db reference

Comment: @Hikari,this is solution for your problem , check this again

Comment: i already implement the solution provide by @97loser but it still popup the same error

Comment: @Hikari, qsUni.documents[i]['name'] before adding this in resultUni check that -qsUni.documents[i]  != null

Comment: here my updated code
     -UniQuery()
          .getUniBasedLocProg(selectedState, selectedProg)
          .then((QuerySnapshot qsUni) {
        if (qsUni.documents.isNotEmpty){
          uniFlag = true;
          for (int i = 0; i < qsUni.documents.length; i++) {
            resultUni.add(qsUni.documents[i]['name']);
          }
        }
        else
          const Text('University not found');
      }); -

but still the same error

Comment: sadly. it still popup same error after i use your updated code
i put my firestore db for reference

Comment: @Hikari,Sorry for that but I can't understand where you have got issues so  can you send error log.

Comment: i have put image error log. 
i also confuse how it can be error

Comment: @Hikari, please check before get data of any reference that ref != null then get data ..,you have to check your code again

Comment: can explain it bit?
i not understand cause i new in flutter